# What is the common dynamic range in "g" of a cell phone accelerometer?

Tags: accelerometer

I am trying to get an idea of what sensor to pick for an application. Right now it is between a [±5 g accelerometer](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/821/mcic_s_a0004994860_1-2295205.pdf) and [±1 g accelerometer](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/821/mcic_s_a0004994793_1-2295249.pdf). The application is similar to that of a cell phone.

Comment: It sees 1g sitting on the table, so that would seem to be ruled out.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The linked 1g accelerometer is 2-axis, so in its intended configuration, it would show 0 g on its axes at rest. This all depends on the OP's exact application. 2-axis sensing is common in cars, for example, since airbags don't do anything for the Z-axis. (Another issue is that the Z-axis tends to have worse performance, since most chips are planar, so you might want to vertically mount a 2-axis chip instead)

Comment: The application is lights responding to the movement of the device. The more the device moves, the more it lights up.

Comment: @adamaero Is it a human picking it up by hand? If so, a 2-axis device is acceptable because it's not reasonable for somebody to pick something up by hand perfectly level.

Comment: Nope. It is hanging.

Comment: @user71659 The comment is based on OP's statement: "The application is similar to that of a cell phone". Maybe it's not very similar.

Comment: Honestly, I couldn't think of any similar application. It's not related to a car. It will probably move as much as a cell phone does if not more. But it will not be used like a cell phone.

Comment: @adamaero Is somebody going to be dancing with it? Is it going to be in a sport where people are kicking it? Or is it going to be swaying in the wind? Those applications all have different accelerations.

Comment: swaying in the wind

Answer (score 1):

The maximum rating of the accelerometer on my phone (Samsung S21) is about 8 g's.

Answer (score 1):

I think "common" is a moving target when it comes to mobile phones. The current Apple iPhone 14 Pro Max uses ([as near as I can research](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+14+Pro+Max+Chip+ID/153224)) a [Bosch Sensortec BMI 270](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/products/motion-sensors/imus/bmi270/) ([datasheet](https://www.bosch-sensortec.com/media/boschsensortec/downloads/datasheets/bst-bmi270-ds000.pdf)) which ranges from ±2 to ±16 g.